# Bigquery unnest vertical array to single cell

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with a field that is of repeated type. I would want the image_url array to be in a single field like a python list or just a comma separated value

[image: existing table something like below]

to something like this

[image: end result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to convert the array to a string.  So one method is `string_agg()`:

```
select id, name, breed,
       (select string_agg(image_url, ',') from  unnest(t.image_url)) as string_Url
from t;
```

If `image_url` is not a string, you may need an explicit `cast()`.

If `image_url` is a string, you can also use `array_to_string()`:

```
select id, name, breed, array_to_string(image_url, ',') as image_url
from t;
```